# Python Socket connection from different device doesnt work

Tags: python, sockets

I created a small chat application on a local server with python. When i run the client code on my own computer it works fine, but when i tried it on another device it says: [WinError 10061] no connection could be made because the target computer activly refused it.
I tried to set the host to “”, i tried to open the port but both didnt work out.
What should i do?
Please dont come with answers like “its probably sth with your firewall” because i know that already. I want to know exactly step by step what to do so it acctually works

my server script:

```py
import threading
import socket

name=socket.gethostname()
host=socket.gethostbyname(name)
port=5050

server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen()

clients=[]
nicknames=[]

def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)

def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message=client.recv(1024)
            broadcast(message)
        except:
            index=clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname=nicknames[index]
            broadcast(f"{nickname} left the chat".encode("ascii"))
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break

def recieve():
    while True:
        client,address=server.accept()
        print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {str(address)} connected with the server!")
        
        client.send("NICK".encode("ascii"))
        nickname=client.recv(1024).decode("ascii")
        
        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)

        client.send("Welcome! you are connected to the server! have fun chatting!".encode("ascii"))        
        broadcast(f"{nickname} joined the chat!".encode("ascii"))

        thread=threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()

print("[LISTENING] server is started and is listening...")
recieve()
```

my client script:

```py
import threading
import socket

print("choose a nickname")
nickname=input()

host=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port=5050

client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((host, port))

def recieve():
    while True:
        try:
            message=client.recv(1024).decode()
            if message=="NICK":
                client.send(nickname.encode("ascii"))
            else:
                print(message)
        except:
            print("an error occurred")
            client.close()
            break

def write():
    while True:
        message="{}: {}".format(nickname, input(""))
        client.send(message.encode("ascii"))

recieve_thread=threading.Thread(target=recieve)
recieve_thread.start()

write_thread=threading.Thread(target=write)
write_thread.start()
```

Comment: please share the code you have already tried and the error stacktrace which you got.

Comment: i added the code. the error is in the description

Answer (score 0):

> when i tried it on another device it says: [WinError 10061] no connection could be made

What exactly is this other device? And where is it located? And where are you opening the socket to?

I assume you're trying to open a socket to a server, and in that case, you have to run the server first before your socket client, before you run your socket program, else you will get a `no connection` error.

Comment: If you have questions it's best to ask them in a comment rather an answer.

Comment: The other device was a computer. Also i did run the server while i ran the client. I got a ConnectionRefusedError

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, I agree with you, but unfortunately, SO blocks users from commenting who have under 50 reps, and at the time of writing this clarifying answer, I did not have 50 reps.